# identifying elements inside div tag array uniquely

Tags: jquery, html

I have a code as follows

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#accordion").accordion();
        });

        var i = 1;

        function pressMe() {
            var h3 = document.createElement("h3"),
                div = document.createElement("div");
            h3.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Section 4'));
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Saurabh'));

            // note the reverse order of adding child        
            h3.appendChild(div);

            //document.getElementById('accordion').appendChild(h3);
            //$( "#accordion" ).accordion();
            $("#accordion").append('<h3>Section ' + ++i + '</h3>         <div id=\'myDiv' + i + '\'>' + document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML + '</div>');
            $("#accordion").accordion("refresh");
        }

        function hide() {
            document.getElementById('temp').style.display = "none";
        }

        function printAll() {
            for (temp = 2; temp <= i; temp++) {
                alert(document.getElementById('myDiv' + temp).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body id="XXX" onload="hide()">
    <div id="accordion">
         <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div id='myDiv1'>
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="pressMe()" value="Add more Nodes">
    <input type="button" onclick="printAll()" value="printAll">
    <div>
        <div id='temp'>
            <input type="text" name="text1" id="id_text">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

all i want to do it i want to uniquely identify all the input tags not by

```
document.getElementById('myDiv' + temp).getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value
```

but using

```
document.getElementById('myDiv' + temp).getElementsById('id_text')[0].value
```

but unable to retrive the element.

Comment: There is no method called `getElementsById`. Why not just `getElementById("id_text")`, as the id must be unique in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('myDiv' + temp)` return a `HTMLElement` which has `getElementsByTagName` method in it prototype (`HTMLElement.prototype.getElementsByTagName`) and don't have `getElementsById` method.

But it has `querySelector` method. You can use it like this:

```
document.getElementById('myDiv' + temp).querySelector('#id_text').value
```

Comment: yes, it worked out in jsfiddle but somehow not in chrome and IE. in eclipse i checked, it didnt show any querySelector Method.

Comment: `Eclipse` is just `IDE`. Not the `W3C` [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#interface-definitions). For me fiddle works in `Chrome` fine.

Comment: you have almost solved my problem but somehow without jsfiddle if i paste the above code in an HTML file and run it standalone chrome, it doesnt work...cant figure it out..

Comment: hey thanks ! this works correctly. small glitch in my code itself...sorry for that..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the Id's and value of the inputs of the elements, then try this:

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <div id='myDiv1'>
           <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" value="a">
           <input type="text" name="text1" id="text2"  value="b">
           <input type="text" name="text1" id="text3"  value="c">
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="pressMe()" value="Add more Nodes">
    <input type="button" onclick="printAll()" value="printAll">
    <div>
       <div id='temp'>
           <input type="text" name="text1" id="id_text">
       </div>
    </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = 1;
    var IDs = [];
    var Values = [];
    var Elements = [];

    $("#myDiv" + temp).find("input").each(function(){
       IDs.push(this.id);           // for ID
       Values.push($(this).val());  // for Value
       Elements.push(this);         // for html tags
    });
    alert(IDs);
});
```